# Is there any way to connect oracle db 11g or uper from visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, oracle

i have old C# project in vs 2008 connected oracle DB but i need to connect another db 12C from this existing project, how can connect two different version of oracle DB from same project in Visual Studio 2008. while i connect twice at a time and publish then it not run...

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Comment: `then it not run` with what error? If the project *compiles* it's not a C# or Visual Studio issue, it can simply be that the project uses an old Oracle Client version. Or that the connection string/credentials are wrong, especially if the program runs on the development machine and only fails after deployment. Or it could be a misconfigured Oracle Home

Comment: ORA 12541:TNS no listener , i also used oraclemanaged.dll it can not loaded